# error: 'serverHandshake' was not declared in this scope

Tags: socket.io, arduino

```
#include <WebSocketClient.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SocketIOClient.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

#define SSID "D"
#define PASS "qwertypoiu"

int keyIndex = 0;                                // your network key Index number
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;  
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
char server[] = "ec2-52-38-82-235.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000";
WebSocketClient client;
void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) 
  {
  SoftwareSerial esp8266Module(10,11);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  client.connect("update trash");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 client.monitor();
 client.send("56fe4b3368fa1b0edd4b44a1,30");
 delay(2000);
}
```

Above is my code i am unable to compile code .error is serverHandshake' was not declared in this scope . I can't any solution . Any help from your side will be appreciated .

Comment: We're not very familiar with that kind of stuff. Stack Exchange has a [special site for Arduino hobbyists!](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) Go ask there. If you get an answer over there, remove this one. Thanks!

Comment: First, please include the **complete** error message. I think one of the files your whihc code `#include`s is missing a the declaration of `serverHandshake` of an `#include` for a file that has that declaration. You might be able to work around this problem by including the file with the declaration in your code explicitly. The real fix would be to fix the header(s) causing this error.

Comment: You define: char server[] = "ec2-52-38-82-235.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000"; but you never use it. It looks like you are missing a call to a function that sets up the server. (Sorry, don't know what function.)